How can I disable file extension correction on macOS Sequoia?
I'm on Sequoia 15.1  beta version.
Whenever I try to save a file with a e.g. a text editor, and it uses the standard macOS file saving dialog, it autocorrects my file endings without asking me. For example, if I name the file .pngg and click on save, it will be saved as .pngg.png. For example, I wanted to save an SQL script, so I named it .sql, and my Mac made it .sql.s.
If you want to try to reproduce:

Grab your favorite text editor (I tested it with Sublime Text, Zed and TextEdit)
If your app uses the standard macOS dialog to save files and does not require a specific file ending. For example, when just opening a new file in Sublime Text and saving it, this worked, but when I choose e.g. Python syntax, macOS will always add .py to your file and doesn't tries to autocorrect it
If you're using TextEdit, Format > Make it plain text, and uncheck the .txt checkbox in the file dialog
Now create any file, save it and name it something with a made up filename, like .txtx which clearly doesn't exist but is similar to .txt, or .exea which will become .exe and so on.
Click on save it look at your filename now.

I can’t tell if this is a feature from the beta or a bug.
Can I prevent this and get files saved exactly how I name them?
Edit
This seems to be a feature / bug added in the Sequoia beta. There's currently no solution for this, if you have problems with it just use the touch command instead, or save and then rename the file.
Look at this for more information:

https://github.com/zed-industries/zed/issues/16969
https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-text-started-adding-a-s-to-new-files-very-annoying/73628/6
https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=41618926


On Sonoma 14.6.1, I could save a text file as file.exea using TextEdit, so it may a new thing (feature or bug, I can't say) with Sequoia. You'll have to ask Apple.

If there's something you don't like in a beta, report it to Apple.

The Settings dialog of TextEdit has an option “Add .txt extension to plain text files.” What happens if you switch that off?

@MartinR it does it ONLY when I switch it off. Otherwise it just alawys inserts .txt
